# Unable to add empty lines

Tags: spacing, titles

I want to add empty lines before the `\date`, in order to put it at the end of the page, but when I try `\\` or `\newline` there is the following error, because of the `\maketitle`. What can I do?

> ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{\bfseries{Title}}
\author{\bfseries{Name
\thanks{E-mail: \bfseries{mail} AM: \texttt{000000}}}}

\affil{Name \\ University \\ Location}

\date{\bfseries{\today}}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[]
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the document class, you can replace the `\maketitle` command with a `titlepage` environment, that lets you compose the title page as you please.  Use the `\vspace` command to add extra vertical space, don **not** add empty lines.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use and how the `\affil` directive is defined.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) and not just a fragment.

Comment: @Mico I use \documentclass{SIAMGHbook2016} from http://www.siam.org/books/authors/formatting.php

Comment: SIAM's [Author handbook](http://www.siam.org/books/authors/p_handbook4.php) specifically states *they* will generate the 'half-title page' and the 'title page'. Are you sure modifying the title page in your source is a good idea?

Comment: also `\title{\bfseries{Title}}` should be `\title{Title}` don't put formatting in these elements as that breaks the idea of `\documentclass` that your journal chooses the document class and _they_ specify the styling for titles etc. Adding formatting there will break the journal style and complicat eextraction of the data for subject classification indexes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use your document class, but perhaps you can help yourself with my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} %OPTIONAL: Just to remove the footnote seperator in order to look as desired

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center} 
\vspace{-0.6cm} %vertical space - not use empty lines
\huge{\textsf{\textbf{My Title}}}
\vspace{1.8cm}

\Large{\textbf{Master's Thesis}}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\large{for obtaining the academic degree} \\
\vspace{0.2cm}

\Large{\textbf{Master of Science (MSc)}} \\
\vspace{0.2cm}

\large{at the \\
University of XXXX} \\
\vspace{2.6cm}

\large{submitted by} \\
\Large{\textbf{Author}\footnote{\textbf{Email:} xxx}} \\
\vspace{2.6cm}

\begin{table} [ht]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{Thesis supervisor:} & XXX \\
\textbf{Thesis advisors:} & YYY \\
\textbf{Thesis assessor:} & ZZZ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace*{\fill} %fill the vertical space until end of the page

\large{May 23, 2018} \\

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

**resulting in:**

[image]

Comment: you have the wrong syntax for size commands `\huge{\textsf{\textbf{My Title}}}` makes all the following text `\huge`  the `{}` around `\textsf` do nothing. Here you over-ride it with a following size command but it would be better to delete the spurious braces as they are misleading. similarly the `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph should not be there (normally latex warns about them but in a `center` environment the warning is not given as an accident of the implementation)